# Как создать скрипт импорта товара с самостоятельным подключением к бд?

Tags: php, opencart

Можно ли как-то создать самостоятельное подключение к бд и сделать импорт товара?
Может быть реализовать это как-то без создания модуля, а сделать файл в корне сайта и импортировать товар.
Такое вообще возможно в опенкарт?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, конечно вы можете создать при должном уровне знаний какой угодно скрипт иморта куда угодно.

Конкретно в opencart вас ждут следующие сложности:

- Информация о товарах и категориях разложена по самым разным местам в
  БД. Например информация о id товара, весе, количестве хранится в
  одном месте, а описание, мета загловки, названия в другом. Категории,
  их описания, связи в третьем. Производители в четвертом.
- При подключении языков, валют - задача соответственно усложняется.

Вот вам схематическая таблица устройства БД opencart

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- При подключении компонентов с кешированием, будь то фильтр вроде brainy filter или условный компонент "ускорения сайта" аля NitroPack после такого
  импорта вам потребуется каждый раз обновлять кеш.

Куда проще не изобретать велосипед, а купить/выбрать бесплатный компонент для импорта и использовать его.

Скрипт же вы можете написать для того, чтобы сформировать из исходных данных файл CSV под требования выбранного модуля импорта/экспорта.

Из того, чем пользовался лично я могу порекомендовать:

- https://opencartforum.com/files/file/467-csv-price-pro-importexport/
- https://opencartforum.com/files/file/811-avtomaticheskaya-obrabotka-prays-listov/

Если всё-же решите создавать самостоятельно, изучите структуру БД opencart вашей версии и раскладывайте через PDO по нужным таблицам считанные из CSV файла данные.

Общепринятый стандарт сравнения элементов файла и таблиц - по product_id, SKU или model.

Comment: подскажите, к примеру взять связь таблиц: `product, product_special, product_discount, product_related, product_reward`, в верхнем левом углу на рисунке.  Это связь один к одному? А разве нельзя это было всё держать в одной таблице? Можете привести пример как эта связь работает?

Comment: product - общие данные продукта. 

product_special - акции на продукт. Они могут быть привязаны к разным группам пользователей и их может быть несколько штук, например одна до НГ, вторая - после. Следовательно их надо хранить отдельно, смотря по product_id к какому товару относится акция. 

product_discount - скидки на продукт. Они тоже могут быть разными, в разные периоды и для разных групп пользователей. 

Ну и т.д. со всем остальным. Разделения вызваны тем функционалом, который заложили в opencart разработчики.

Comment: Проще всего вам будет создать пару товаров с разными данными и покопаться через phpmyadmin в них, чтобы понять как это работает. Если кратко, то связи на картинки - по product_id, а так их очень много по тому или иному id в зависимости от области сайта. На картинке линиями показано какая строчка определяет зависимость. Например manufacturer_id определяет связь товара с производителем.

Comment: а если нужно просто один раз выполнить php-скрипт без создания модуля, т.е. к примеру сделать всего одну запись в базу данных, как этот скрипт можно выполнить и откуда запустить? его нужно добавить в корень сайта и оттуда запустить? подскажите, как это правильно сделать?

Comment: т.е. к примеру нужно добавить всего один товар, но модуль для этого делать не нужно

Comment: это нужно сделать с созданием нового подключения к бд